# How do I create a grid in google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

What I'm trying to do is, created 2 markers (they are draggable), there will be grid between them, like http://prntscr.com/4nx9f3.
[image]

When I change one of the marker, grid should be changed. I am trying to draw with polylines. By the way i can not get latitude or longitute with `marker1.getPosition().lat()`.

all my code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          html, body, #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
          }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
        <script>
            var map;
            var marker1;
            var marker2;


            function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 10,
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.3, 44.3)
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
          mapOptions);

                marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.1, 44.1),
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    title: 'marker1 '

                });
                marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.5, 44.5),
                    map: map,
                    draggable: true,
                    title: 'marker2'
                });


                var flightPlanCoordinates = [
                    marker1.getPosition(),
                    marker2.getPosition(),
                 ];

                // code below is not working
                /* 
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function () {

                polyline.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()));
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'dragend', function () {

                polyline.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()));
        
                */
                var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline(
                { path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                    geodesic: true,
                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                });

                var lat1 = marker1.getPosition().lat();
                var lng1 = marker1.getPosition().lng();
                var lat2 = marker2.getPosition().lat();
                var lng2 = marker2.getPosition().lng();

                // I tried to get distance between 2 markers but it did not work either
                /*   function distance(
                lat1, 
                lng1, 
                lat2, 
                lng2
                ) {
                var R = 6371;
                var a =
                0.5 - Math.cos((lat2 - lat1) * Math.PI / 180) / 2 +
                Math.cos(lat1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.cos(lat2 * Math.PI / 180) *
                (1 - Math.cos((lon2 - lon1) * Math.PI / 180)) / 2;

                return R * 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(a));
                }
                */


                polyline.setMap(map);

            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do.  Changed your rectangleLng array to a two dimensional array and changed the excLat/excLng variables to not be rounded (they were backwards as well extLat wants to be up/down, excLng should be side to side).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t13oz5xt/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var marker1;
var marker2;
var rectangle;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.4, 26.7)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.3, 26.6),
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'marker1'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function(evt) {
    infowindow.setContent(marker1.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.5, 26.8),
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'marker2'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', function(evt) {
    infowindow.setContent(marker1.getPosition().toUrlValue(6));
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
  rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      marker1.getPosition(),
      marker2.getPosition())
  });

  var leftSideDist = Math.round((marker2.getPosition().lng() - marker1.getPosition().lng()) * 10000) / 100;
  var belowSideDist = Math.round((marker2.getPosition().lat() - marker1.getPosition().lat()) * 10000) / 100;

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function() {

    rectangle.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()));
    leftSideDist = Math.round((marker2.getPosition().lng() - marker1.getPosition().lng()) * 10000) / 100;
    makeGrid();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'dragend', function() {

    rectangle.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()));
    belowSideDist = Math.round((marker2.getPosition().lat() - marker1.getPosition().lat()) * 10000) / 100;
    makeGrid();
  });
  makeGrid();
}

var rectangleLat = [];
var rectangleLng = [];

function makeGrid() {
  for (x in rectangleLng) {
    for (y in rectangleLng[x]) {
      if (rectangleLng[x][y].setMap) {
        rectangleLng[x][y].setMap(null)
        rectangleLng[x][y] = null;
      }
    }
  }
  var leftSideDist = marker2.getPosition().lng() - marker1.getPosition().lng();
  var belowSideDist = marker2.getPosition().lat() - marker1.getPosition().lat();

  var dividerLat = 5;
  var dividerLng = 5; //ilerde kullanıcıdan alınacak
  var excLat = belowSideDist / dividerLat;
  var excLng = leftSideDist / dividerLng;

  var m1Lat = marker1.getPosition().lat();
  var m1Lng = marker1.getPosition().lng();
  var m2Lat = marker2.getPosition().lat();
  var m2Lng = marker2.getPosition().lng();
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "dividerLat=" + dividerLat + ", excLat=" + excLat + "<br>";
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "dividerLng=" + dividerLat + ", excLng=" + excLng + "<br>";
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "m1=" + marker1.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "m2=" + marker2.getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + "<br>";

  for (var i = 0; i < dividerLat; i++) {
    if (!rectangleLng[i]) rectangleLng[i] = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < dividerLng; j++) {
      if (!rectangleLng[i][j]) rectangleLng[i][j] = {};


      rectangleLng[i][j] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
        strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.1,
        map: map,
        bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
          new google.maps.LatLng(m1Lat + (excLat * i), m1Lng + (excLng * j)),
          new google.maps.LatLng(m1Lat + (excLat * (i + 1)), m1Lng + (excLng * (j + 1))))

      });
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "[i=" + i + ",j=" + j + "]:" + rectangleLng[i][j].getBounds() + "<br>";



    } //for j Lng

  } //for i Lat


  document.getElementById('left').value = leftSideDist;
  document.getElementById('blw').value = belowSideDist;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
#panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -180px;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  /* border: 1px solid #999;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<div id="panel" style="margin-left:-320px">leftSideDist:
  <input type="text" readonly id="left">belowSideDist:
  <input type="text" readonly id="blw">
</div>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the coordinates of the marker after it's been dragged, change:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function() {
      polyline.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()));
  });
```

to:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function(event) {
      polyline.LatLngBounds(event.latLng);
  });
```

**However**, there is no `LatLngBounds` function on the polyline object.

Comment: i handled with dragend, now i just need to create grid on these two markers

Comment: how do you define your grid - you want to always have the same number of lines between the points, i.e. the gaps between the lines could change as the markers are dragged?  Or you always have grid lines drawn x metres apart, so as you drag a marker you may need to add or remove lines?

Comment: yes, for now i want to create 25 rectangles (5x5) inside these 2 markers. but when i change either marker positions, boxes would change

Answer (score 0):

```
As far as i done:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?          
    sensor=false&v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
    <script>
        var map;
        var marker1;
        var marker2;
        var rectangle;

        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 11,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.4, 26.7)
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

            marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.3, 26.6),
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                title: 'marker1'
            });
            marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(38.5, 26.8),
                map: map,
                draggable: true,

                title: 'marker2'
            });

            rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: map,
                bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                        marker1.getPosition(),
                        marker2.getPosition())
            });

            var leftSideDist = Math.round((marker2.getPosition().lng() - marker1.getPosition().lng()) * 10000) / 100;
            var belowSideDist = Math.round((marker2.getPosition().lat() - marker1.getPosition().lat()) * 10000) / 100;

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function () {

                rectangle.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()));
                leftSideDist = Math.round((marker2.getPosition().lng() - marker1.getPosition().lng()) * 10000) / 100;
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'dragend', function () {

                rectangle.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()));
                belowSideDist = Math.round((marker2.getPosition().lat() - marker1.getPosition().lat()) * 10000) / 100;
            });



            var leftSideDist = Math.round((marker2.getPosition().lng() - marker1.getPosition().lng()) * 10000) / 100;
            var belowSideDist = Math.round((marker2.getPosition().lat() - marker1.getPosition().lat()) * 10000) / 100;

            var dividerLat = 5;
            var dividerLng = 5; //ilerde kullanıcıdan alınacak
            var excLat = leftSideDist / dividerLat;
            var excLng = belowSideDist / dividerLng;

            var rectangleLat[];
            var rectangleLng[];

            var m1Lat = marker1.getPosition().lat();
            var m1Lng = marker1.getPosition().lng();
            var m2Lat = marker2.getPosition().lat();
            var m2Lng = marker2.getPosition().lng();

            for (var i = 0; i < dividerLat; i++) {

                for (var j = 0; j < dividerLng; j++) {



                    rectangleLng[i*5+j] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: '#FF0000',
                        fillOpacity: 0.35,
                        map: map,
                        bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
                        ( m1Lat , (excLng*(j+1) ) ),
                        ( m1Lat+excLat, m2Lng+(excLng*(j+1) ) ) )

                    });



                }//for j Lng

             }//for i Lat


            document.getElementById('left').value = leftSideDist;
            document.getElementById('blw').value = belowSideDist;
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    <div id="panel" style="margin-left:-320px">
      leftSideDist: <input type="text" readonly id="left">
      belowSideDist: <input type="text" readonly id="blw">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```