# Dividing City by Longitude and Latitude into Matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, geolocation, data-visualization

How do you divide a city such as San Francisco into equally sized blocks according to longitude and latitude coordinates? The aim of this is when I receive a coordinate of a location in the city I want to assign it automatically into one of these blocks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a Grid is the viewing area of a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368644/how-to-create-a-grid-is-the-viewing-area-of-a-map)

Comment: related question: [Grid on top of Google maps produces gaps in squares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493098/grid-on-top-of-google-maps-produces-gaps-in-squares)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a grid in google maps api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908973/how-do-i-create-a-grid-in-google-maps-api-v3)

Comment: Also look into implementing your own Geohash or use libraries publicly available.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple use of the publicly available python library module Geohash (https://github.com/vinsci/geohash).

A python hashmap (dictionary) is used to map Geohash strings to lists of lat/lng points which have been added in the area ("block") represented by the Geohash.  A query is performed by computing a position's Geohash and accessing the hashmap for that entry to retrieve all of the entries for that "block".

```
    ### Add position to Geohash
    ###    Each hash mapping contains a list of points in the "block"
    ### 
    def addToGeohash(m, latitude, longitude):
        p = (latitude, longitude)
        ph = encode(p[0],p[1],5)
        if ph not in m:
            m[ph] = []
        m[ph].append(p)
        return

    ### Get positions in same "block"   or empty list if none found
    ###
    def getFromGeohash(m, latitude, longitude):
      p = (latitude, longitude)
      ph = encode(p[0],p[1],5)
      print ("query hash: " + ph)
      if ph in m:
        return m[ph]
      return []


    ### Test
    m = dict()

    # Add 2 points in general area (1st near vista del mar)
    addToGeohash(m, 37.779914,-122.509431)
    addToGeohash(m, 37.780546,-122.366189)

    # Query a point 769 meters from vista del mar point
    n = getFromGeohash(m, 37.779642,-122.502993)

    print ("Length of hashmap: "+str(len(m)))
    print ("Contents of map  : "+str(m))
    print ("Query result     : ")
    print (n)
```

The default precision is 12 characters (5 was used in example) and will affect the dictionary mapping efficiency or "block" size.

Note that using a lat/lng based approach is a non-linear and so over vast areas or closer to poles would not be "equal sized blocks".  However,
over the area of San Fransisco and with sufficient precision, this non-linearity is reduced significantly.

Output

```
query hash: 9q8yu
Length of hashmap: 2
Contents of map  : {'9q8yu': [(37.779914, -122.509431)], '9q8yz': [(37.780546, -122.366189)]}
Query result     :
    [(37.779914, -122.509431)]
```

To get a sense of the block size for various precisions use this [link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/geohash.html) and enter for example 37.779914,-122.509431 and a precision of 5.  Experiment with precision.

Here are the approximate box sizes for precisions 5-8:

```
5 ≤ 4.89km × 4.89km 
6 ≤ 1.22km × 0.61km 
7 ≤ 153m × 153m 
8 ≤ 38.2m × 19.1m
```

An interesting feature of the Geohash which works mostly (and always with the SanFran area) is you can easily find the 8 adjacent neighbors by manipulating the last character.  So, with minimal effort you could use a higher precision (e.g. 8) and reduce it to a size between 7 and 8.

Answer (score 0):

the naive approach is to find a big enough rectangle around the whole city (area you want to cover) and by the number of blocks desired you can deduce to how many parts divide the rectangular edges, it should be a fairly basic math
given a point you can assign it to it's block in a very fast way (just check it's lan and long see where it falls in the grid)

Answer (score 0):

I've written different versions of this algorithm over the years. Spent a lot of time mulling over the problem. There are two issues involved:

1. Mapping 2-dimensional coordinates into a 1-dimensional value. (Fundamentally, in order to do this optimally, you must know the bounds of both dimensions)
2. Cutting the plane covering a sphere roughly into "squares". (The squares are different sizes as you get closer to the poles. Also, they're never actually squares, but the earth is so huge this usually doesn't matter)

This is some code that I did that suited my purpose. A few things to consider:

- This creates blocks of a set size that you designate. The python Geohash library does this cool thing where the hash can be truncated to produce hashes of larger sizes. This algorithm does not do that, but on the flip side you can specify your desired block size (roughly).
- This actually creates two-dimensional coordinates that I treat as a 1-dimensional string. I do this because its good enough for me and I can easily manipulate the string data to get the adjacent blocks in a way that is clear and makes sense. For example the hash: "-23,407" is 23 blocks west and 407 blocks north of the center point. So if you want to move one block to the east, you just add 1 to -23: "-22,407".
- The center point that I used here is the middle of Washington DC. You could use center point 0,0, or the middle of San Francisco or whatever. But do not use center points near the poles: -90,-180. because when the algorithm goes to calculate the longitude offset in kilometers, it will calculate the distance between (-90, your-longitude) and (-90, -180). These points are at the south pole (I think the south pole?) and the distance will be infinitesimally small because at the poles all of these blocks are extremely small.

This is the main algorithm to hash the points:

```
# Define center point
CENTER_LAT = 38.893
CENTER_LNG = -77.084

def geohash(lat, lng, BLOCK_SIZE_KM=.05):
    # Get Latitude Offset
    lat_distance = haversine_km(
        (CENTER_LAT, CENTER_LNG),
        (lat,        CENTER_LNG)
    )
    if lat < CENTER_LAT:
        lat_distance = lat_distance*-1
    lat_offset = int(lat_distance/BLOCK_SIZE_KM)

    # Get Longitude offset
    lng_distance = haversine_km(
        (CENTER_LAT, CENTER_LNG),
        (CENTER_LAT, lng)
    )
    if lng < CENTER_LNG:
        lng_distance = lng_distance*-1
    lng_offset = int(lng_distance/BLOCK_SIZE_KM)

    block_str = '%s,%s' % (lat_offset, lng_offset)

    return block_str
```

I included these helper functions for calculating the distance between two coordinates:

```
def haversine_km(origin, destination):
    return haversine(origin, destination, 6371)

def haversine(origin, destination, radius):
    lat1, lon1 = origin
    lat2, lon2 = destination

    lat1 = float(lat1)
    lon1 = float(lon1)
    lat2 = float(lat2)
    lon2 = float(lon2)

    dlat = math.radians(lat2-lat1)
    dlon = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
    a = math.sin(dlat/2) * math.sin(dlat/2) + math.cos(math.radians(lat1)) \
        * math.cos(math.radians(lat2)) * math.sin(dlon/2) * math.sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1-a))
    d = radius * c

    return d
```